# run console application from another console application c# error file not found

Tags: c#, io, console-application, diagnostics

I am tryinng to execute a console application from another console application and im getting an error file not found although the path is correct i keep getting errors,the path is:

> C:\Users\Malka\Desktop\RecomendedArtists\GetID\GetID\bin\Debug\GetID.exe

the code is:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(AppDir()+@"GetID\GetID\bin\Debug\GetID.exe");

public static string AppDir()
{
    string x = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string b = x.Substring(0, x.Length - 31);
    return b;
}
```

[image]

[image]

if someone knows why i am getting the error it will help a lot THX.

Comment: It would probably help you debug by outputting the path to the console first (`Console.WriteLine(path);`).

Comment: First: You should use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to concatenate a valid path. Second: which line throws the error? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine` to make the path: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(AppDir(), @"GetID\GetID\bin\Debug\GetID.exe"));`

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't fix it, I have tried a few formats of running the file, first I tried executing the solution but it just opened the VS so I tried to open the .exe file in the Debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It doesn't appear to be giving an error - just that you are not seeing the new application run.

GetCurrentDirectory might not be where you think it is (especially if running this in Debug in Visual Studio).

As well as following einord's suggestion to output the path for debug purposes, check the return Process object of Start().  Null means it didn't create the process - anything else means it did but you can't see it for some reason.

I'd also check in Task Manager that an instance of GetID isn't running somewhere (as in that case Start() will fail and return null).